# MTM requirements vs links vs tested userstories/backlog

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, alm, mtm

In Microsoft test manager, there are 3 ways to attach a requirement to test case

```
1) contents->add requirement
2) open the test case ->"test user-stories" tab
3) Links -> which adds a tested-by link for requirements
```

1. Why so many options to do the same thing? Or are there difference?
2. Why call #1 "requirement" and #2 user-stories/Product backlog?
3. When I use #1 then #3 is also added. But why not #2?

Answer (score 0):

I think Question 2 is a mistake from Microsoft. In terms of improper User Interface design.

For Question 3, #2 will be added if we use "tests" link instead of "tested by"

This is what I found from [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/eranruso/2009/12/30/tfs-2010-work-items-basic-user-guide-work-item-link-types/) `"Tests" when used from a Test Case means that the Test Case covers the linked Work Item, it can be a bug, an issue or a requirement.
"Tested By" is the opposite direction of “Tests” link, you use it from bugs, issues, requirements etc. the linked Work item will be Test case.`

Comment: A "requirement" is a generic... User Story and PBI are specific types of requirements.